# How to compare two dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'aaa',50],[0,'aaa',1000],[0,'aba',30],[1,'aaa',50],[1,'aba',10]], 
columns=['A','B','C'])
df



    A   B   C
0   1   aaa 50
1   0   aaa 1000
2   0   aba 30
3   1   aaa 50
4   1   aba 10
```

I want for each item in 'B'(which also there are repeated items), check its value in 'A'. If it's 1, it should calculate the sum of values in 'C' for that item. If it's 0, it should count the number of items which their 'A' value is zero. Then the final result would be: sum/count.

In the end, I want to show the result like this:

```
    ID  Value
0   aaa 100
1   aba 10
```

For example, 'aaa' has two 1 which their sum is 50 + 50 = 100, and one 0 which its count is 1. So the result is 100 / 1 = 100.

How can I do something like that in an efficient way? I tried to use groupby() and have the sum and count in different dataframes, but I don't know how to compare them and get this result.

Comment: Why is `aaa`, `0` not returning nothing (or 0) given that there are no entries, making your first output inf? What you're doing right now just seems to be summing within groups for entries where `A == 1`

Comment: @ifly6 that's true, because here 'aaa' has only repeated once in 'A ==0'. So it counts as 1 and the sum/count would be as 100/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) on columns `A` and `B`, while summing and sizing the `C` column. Then divide `A==1` 'sum' by `A==0` 'count':

```
new_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).aggregate(sum=('C', 'sum'), count=('C', 'size'))
new_df = (new_df.loc[1, 'sum'] / new_df.loc[0, 'count']).reset_index()
new_df.columns = ['ID', 'Value']  # Rename Columns
```

`new_df`:

```
    ID  Value
0  aaa  100.0
1  aba   10.0
```

*Beware division by 0. It is possible some group would have 0 entries for a given B value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need to count 0 values in 'A' too and in the end divide the sum by count for each item. In this example, the count is 1, but my dataset is too big and I have to consider that. Here the Value 100 for 'aaa' is actually 100/1.

Comment: This does divide sum by count groupby both A and B aggregate sum and count. Then divide A=1 sum by A=0 count.

Comment: I consider that. Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [90]: df[df['A'] == 1].groupby('B')['C'].sum() /  df[df['A'] == 0].groupby('B').size()
Out[90]:
B
aaa    100.0
aba     10.0
dtype: float64
```

this should take care of dividing correctly as both the series are indexed by the column `'B'` because of the grouping

Comment: I like this approach on separate filtering and groupbys. You might consider throwing a `reset_index` in there to turn back into a frame.

Comment: That helped me. Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a groupy and select the right group:

import pandas as pd

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().loc[1]

B      C
aaa  100
aba   10
```